# How to create a new line in combination with ^FH?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I've been trying to get ZPL working with a combination of `^FH` and new lines. For some reason when I use the following code

`^FH\^FD<RECEIVERNAME>\&<RECEIVERSTREET>\&<RECEIVERHOUSENUMBER>^FS`

It ends up as

`<RECEIVERNAME>&<RECEIVERSTREET>&<RECEIVERHOUSENUMBER>`

I cannot seem to figure out how to stop `^FH` from converting the new line to a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Hex for a new line is 0a, and hex for carriage return is 0d.

Neither of them work with http://labelary.com/ so I'm guessing that they are not supported for what you are using them for.

Answer (score 0):

Line break characters (`0x0d` and/or `0x0a`) like any other nonprintable characters are not supported in the commands `^FD`, `^FV` and `^SN`, as stated in the [ZPL Programming Guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf). See the description of the `^FD` command for reference.

Answer (score -1):

I make it working with ^FH by placing command `\&` on start of new line in code...

I am sending the zpl via php script. In php new line to zpl code must be placed by `"\n"`

like this -> `'zpl code'."\n".'zpl code'`
New line `\n` must be in double quotes.

**Not working example:**

```
^FB^FH^FD
Name\&
Street\&
City\&
ZIP
^FS
```

**Working example**

```
^FB^FH^FD
Name
\&Street
\&City
\&ZIP
^FS
```

Never make it work with code in one zpl line in.

Comment: The reason why `\&` works here is that you are using `^FB`, which is specifically a multiline box that uses `\&` as the escape sequence for "new line". It does not work outside of `^FB`. It does not require a PHP new line either.